Changing a double bowl kitchen sink into a single bowl with an offset drain
Renovating our kitchen and I will have a plumber do the work. I'm looking at workstation sinks and have read somewhere that ideally a workstation sink should have an offset drain.  Would it matter where the sink drain would be located relative to your dishwasher?  My dishwasher is on the right but the sink I'm interested in has an offset drain to the left.  Would this be a problem?  I'm also worried that there would be a problem with installing a garbage disposal under the drain (it being located on the upper left side of the sink).  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Shouldn't be a problem. Dishwasher drain hoses are flexible. At worst you might need to extend or replace that hose. Extending should be fairly easy.

I would think the only trouble with a disposal would be if the new sink is much deeper than the old.
